# Update React Components Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm struggled in update an Array containing react components that i also use as state.

This is my parent state:

```
const [result, setResult] = useState(0)
const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([])
```

inside inputList i have multiple child components defined like this:

```
<Row key={calculateId(inputList)} id={calculateId(inputList)} parentCallback={removeRow} updateValue={calculateRes} value={0} sign={'plus'} enabled={true}/>
```

Now, when input changes on child component, new value will be returned to the parent through a callback, but i can't update state because i can't clone the previous array to set the new one updated.
I don't know if this mechanism is the right one, if you have any suggestions please do not hesitate to reply
Thank you in advance!

Comment: see this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26254086/5982721

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback function of setState.

For example.

```
const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([])

// some code

setInputList((prevStae) => {
   return prevState.map(item => {
      // some mutations for item
      return item;
    })
})
```